# object is null for string.Any(f =>)

Tags: c#, .net

I have a function:

```
public bool IsValidFileSelection(string[] fileNames)
{
   bool isValid = false;

   // There is no need to check the file types here.
   // As it is been restricted by the openFileBrowse

   if (fileNames != null && fileNames.Count() > 0)
   {
      if (fileNames.Count() == 1 && 
            fileNames.Any( f => Path.GetExtension(f) == ".jpg" 
                               || Path.GetExtension(f) == ".png")) 
      {
          isValid = true;
      }
      else
      {
          // If multiple files are there. none shoulf be of type .lfa
          isValid = fileNames.Any( f => Path.GetExtension(f) == ".jpg" 
                              || Path.GetExtension(f) == ".png");
       }
   }

   return isValid;
}
```

I cant seem to figure out why my use of string[].Any( f => Path.GetExtension(f) returns a null object for f.  I am using this to try to see if my file objects in a multi-select open file dialog are all jpg or png as thse are the only types I want to allow.  Is this not the best way to go about this?  Why is my object (f) null?

Comment: Well presumably `fileNames` contains a null value. But your logic is very strange at the moment. Why all the calls to `Count()`? Why the same condition in two different places? Why refer to lfa files in a comment and then not in the code?

Comment: Why even have the inner `if`? The `Any` check will work whether there is one or more than one.

Comment: This code can be simplified greatly. For starters, `fileNames.Count()` should be `fileNames.Length`, and in your check where `fileNames.Length == 1`, after that there is no reason to use LINQ as you've just confirmed that `fileNames` contains only one member which can be referenced by `fileNames[0]`.

Comment: Not to mention duplicate code `.Any()` smells of copy/paste programming.

Comment: Are ".JPG" and ".PNG" not allowed?

Comment: You are correct this is cut and paste code.  After reviewing I really don't need to use linq but I am curious as to why the object is null when fileNames contains two strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would simplify this and make it much faster (by avoid uncessary calls to `.Any()` or `.Count()`)

```
class Program
{
    static readonly string[] valid_ext = new[] { ".jpg", ".png" };

    public bool IsValidFileSelection(params string[] filenames)
    {

        if(filenames==null) return false;
        if(filenames.Length==0) return false;

        foreach(var item in filenames)
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(item)) return false;
            if(!valid_ext.Contains(Path.GetExtension(item)))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

and here is the test suite I used

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new Program();

        Debug.Assert(p.IsValidFileSelection()==false);
        Debug.Assert(p.IsValidFileSelection("a.jpg")==true);
        Debug.Assert(p.IsValidFileSelection("a.png")==true);
        Debug.Assert(p.IsValidFileSelection("a.jpg", "a.png")==true);
        Debug.Assert(p.IsValidFileSelection("a.jpg", "a.png", "a.lfa")==false);
        Debug.Assert(p.IsValidFileSelection("a.lfa")==false);
        Debug.Assert(p.IsValidFileSelection("a.png",null)==false);
    }
```

Comment: You might want to include an `item == null` check in there as well, since OP's question involves an object in `filenames` being null.

Comment: Oh yes. I forgot. I am editing now. Thank you @Abion47

Comment: As I can see, you ignore *all*, but the *last item* in the array, that's why you can change the entire loop into `LastOrDefault` command.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko ...No, he's not? He's iterating through each element and checking it individually. `LastOrDefault` would be clunky to use. If anything, the loop can be replaced with an `Any`, but it would only be for cleanliness of code since the manual approach is almost always faster than the equivalent LINQ method.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I am going through the entire list with `foreach(var item in filenames)` and checking for cases where extensions are _not_ valid. If I find a non-valid case I short-circuit the logic and just return `false`. Otherwise I return `true`. It's a common pattern in programming.

Comment: @ja72: Nothing wrong with your implementation (it does pass the tests, +1), but I personally doubt if performance is the issue in the context (obtaining `arg` via `Directory.GetFiles` or alike is the time consuming process); the real problem, IMHO, is *readability* which was the main cause of the question.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko My main goal with the answer was readability (clarity of process). Any code efficiency was just habit.

Answer (score 0):

A solution has already been chosen, but for completeness's sake, I'll include a LINQ option:

```
public bool IsValidFileSelection(params string[] filenames)
{
    if (filenames == null || filenames.Length == 0)
        return false;

    return filenames.All(f => f != null && 
               (Path.GetExtension(f) == ".jpg" || Path.GetExtension(f) == ".png"))
}
```